# Reputation points documentation

Tags: discussion

Is there some documentation that tells exactly how you get reputation points on askubuntu?  I have been here one day and I have 23 reputation points but I have no idea how I got them and I can not find any documentation on the site.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a recap of the points on your personal page: https://askubuntu.com/users/119046/user119046

It will lead to this part that shows it per answer per question: 
https://askubuntu.com/users/119046/user119046?tab=reputation

- +15 / -2   7 hours ago    4 events     How do symbolic links work in Dropbox?
- +5     13 hours ago   upvote  Can you make nautilus ask for verification before deleting a file?
- +2     13 hours ago   accept  New to Unity. 3 quick questions:
- +2     13 hours ago   accept  Can you make nautilus ask for verification before deleting a file?

So 1 point has not been counted yet ;)

---

And here is an explanation for the points itself: https://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation